# Function to convert a nested object list to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to convert a nested object list to an array but i am getting back an array of undefined.

```
function listToArray(a) {
    let list = { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }; 
    let array = [list.val];
    while(list.rest !== null) {
        list = list.rest;
        array.push(list.val);   
    }
    return array;
}
console.log(listToArray(a));
```

The actual result is: [ undefined, undefined, undefined ] 
But i want to be this: [1,2,3]

Comment: You've written `list.val` instead of `list.value`.

Comment: Make up your mind: `val` or `value`.

Comment: Its value.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `val`, not `value`:

```js
function listToArray() {
  let list = {value: 1,rest: {value: 2,rest: {value: 3,rest: null}}};
  let array = [list.value];
  while (list.rest !== null) {
    list = list.rest;
    array.push(list.value);
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(listToArray());
```

Alternatively, you can use a simple recursive solution:

```js
let list = {value: 1,rest: {value: 2,rest: {value: 3,rest: null}}};

function listToArray(obj) {
  let result = [obj.value]
  if (obj.rest) result = result.concat(listToArray(obj.rest));
  return result;
}
console.log(listToArray(list));
```

Comment: With list.value it worked.I saw a similar code written with .val and i assumed that this was the correct choice.Thank you for the solution,and also for the recursive solution!!

Comment: No problem @georgemoraitis, if my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Jack , i am new here and  i am new in the programming also.Trying to learn.